# Windows cmd.exe Variable Substitutions in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Is there a method available in VB.NET through which I can do Windows cmd.exe like Variable substitutions?

For example:
"anyname_%date:~-4,10%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.xml"

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to apply the same logic, without rewriting it all yourself, or are you asking if there is a way to do something similar yourself?

Comment: I prefer to apply the same logic, without rewriting it all myself. I know I could code the same logic, but that would be elaborate and quiet silly if there is already a method available.

Comment: Agreed.  Since that's what you meant, I think it's a great question (one for which I don't have an answer).  I was just honestly confused by your question.  The way it's worded, it wasn't clear which thing you were after.